# How to prevent SQL injection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel, even new to the PHP framework. I want to know which one will be the best approach to prevent SQL injection. Below are the 2 queries, which one will prevent the SQL injection? If none give me your solution, I will be thankful to you.

```
// Query # 1
DB::insert(' Insert into user(id, name) values(?,?)', [null, $name] ) 

// Query # 2
DB::insert( DB::raw("Insert into user(id, name) values(null, '$name')") )
```

Comment: Use DB::escape, Eloquent has SQLIA prevent mechanisms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query # 1 
you better use a prepared statement and avoid the second way

Comment: Thanks, bro, I just found the Query # 2, cannot prevent SQL injection.
I'm going for Query # 1.

Comment: @MuradAli welcome, flag the Answer as the right answer please if it is correct for you